# include files depended on target

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile which includes makefiles from sub-directories.
However, what I want is to include these "sub"-makefiles on base of a selected target.

Background is, that the sub-makefiles define different object files and depending on these object files the target executable should be created.

Assuming sub-makefile1 sets the variable

```
OBJECTS := foo.o foo1.o
```

sub-makefile2 sets

```
OBJECTS := bar.o bar1.o
```

And the generic rule would be:

```
lib/%.so: $(OBJECTS)
    link $^ -o $@
```

The targets are (for example):

```
foo: lib/foo.so
```

```
bar: lib/bar.so
```

whereas target foo should include the foo makefile, target bar the bar-makefile.

Any idea how to handle this situation?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific thing you're asking for -- conditional inclusion -- is difficult in Make. It can be done, but it's not elegant.

There are several ways to get the effect you want. You could use a conditional on MAKECMDGOALS. You could could have your makefile invoke a second makefile, and pass it the name of the subdirectory to use. But (without knowing more about the situation) I think this way is the tidiest:

```
include sub-makefile1
FOO_OBJECTS := $(OBJECTS)

include sub-makefile2
BAR_OBJECTS := $(OBJECTS)

lib/%.so:
    link $^ -o $@

lib/foo.so: $(FOO_OBJECTS)

lib/bar.so: $(BAR_OBJECTS)

foo bar : % : lib/%.so
```

(You could be clever with variable names like `foo_OBJECTS` to save a line or two, but I advise against that.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, I wasn't aware that I don't need the prerequisites for the lib/%.so: rule, or in fact that they are forwarded from the lib/foo.so: rule. Also the thing with the static pattern rule are new to me. You example is exactly that what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Beta has mentioned the `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`, but not described it:

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),foo)
include sub-makefile1
endif
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),bar)
include sub-makefile2
endif

# Rest of Makefile follows...
```

This isn't such a great idea, as it will only work when `make` is called interactively. You can hack around this by making rules for `foo` and `bar` that recursively invoke `make`:

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),foo)
include sub-makefile1
foo: # ...
    # Normal commands to build foo
else
foo:
    $(MAKE) $<
endif

ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),bar)
include sub-makefile2
bar: # ...
    # Normal commands to build bar
else
bar:
    $(MAKE) $<
endif
```